# side by side plot with igraph

Tags: r, pdf, plot

I tried to plot two graphs side by side in one page of the pdf file as follow:

```
library(igraph)
library(ggplot2)
post <- topicmodels::posterior(ldaOut)
layout(matrix(1,1 byrow = TRUE))
cor_mat <- cor(t(post[["terms"]]))
cor_mat[ cor_mat < .05 ] <- 0
diag(cor_mat) <- 0
graph <- graph.adjacency(cor_mat, weighted=TRUE, mode="lower")
graph <- delete.edges(graph, E(graph)[ weight < 0.05])
E(graph)$edge.width <- E(graph)$weight* 15
V(graph)$label <- paste("Topic", V(graph))
V(graph)$size <- colSums(post[["topics"]]) * 2
set.seed(110)
pdf("all.pdf", width=400,height=350,res=72)
p1 <- plot.igraph(graph, edge.width = E(graph)$edge.width, 
    edge.color = "blue", vertex.color = "green", 
    vertex.frame.color = NA, vertex.label.color = "black")
clp <- cluster_label_prop(graph)
class(clp)
p2 <- plot(clp, graph, edge.width = E(graph)$edge.width, edge.color = "blue",vertex.color = "green")
pushViewport(viewport(layout = grid.layout(1, 2)))
print(p1, vp = viewport(layout.pos.row = 1, layout.pos.col = 1))
print(p2, vp = viewport(layout.pos.row = 1, layout.pos.col = 2))
dev.off()
```

but the results shows the two plots in two separated pages rather than one page. Any recommendation on how to fix this issue?

Comment: post reproducible example. What is `ldaOut`, `post`?

Comment: Try replacing your `layout` statement with `par(mfrow=c(1,2))`

Comment: @PoGibas these are my processed dataset, and i don't have issue with that. My issue from the plots results.

Comment: @G5W the issue still same, it prints the two separated plots in to pages of the pdf.

Comment: Doh,  I should have seen this.  Please put the `par(mfrow=c(1,2))` immediately after your `pdf` statement `pdf("all.pdf", width=400,height=350,res=72)`

Comment: Great, that saves my time, thank you very much. It works !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So that the question has an answer ...

The problem is that when you change to a new graphics device with your `pdf` statement,  you lose any indication that you wanted a 1-by-2 display of graphs.   A solution is to add

```
par(mfrow=c(1,2))
```

immediately after your pdf statement.  It is possible that your `layout` statement would have worked had it been placed there.